# Prolog infinite loop

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, failure-slice, b-prolog, xsb

This is a program that should find out who is compatible with john.
I am new to Prolog. In order to let Prolog know eg. met(X,Y) = met (Y,X)
lots of code has been written.
Now when I start the query

```
?- compatible(john, X)
```

it goes into infinite looping...

Source code:

```
compatible(X,Y) :- reading(X), reading(Y).
compatible(X,Y) :- football(X), football(Y).
compatible(X,Y) :- friends(X,Y).
compatible(X,Y) :- mutual(X,Y).
friends(X,Y) :- havemet(X,Y), compatible(X,Y).
havemet(X,Y) :- met(X,Y).
havemet(X,Y) :- met(Y,X).
mutual(X,Y) :- friends(X,Temp), friends(Y,Temp).
mutual(X,Y) :- friends(Temp,X), friends(Y,Temp).
mutual(X,Y) :- friends(X,Temp), friends(Temp,Y).
mutual(X,Y) :- friends(Temp,X), friends(Temp,Y).

football(john).
football(james).
friends(john, carl).
friends(carl, john).
reading(carl).
reading(fred).
reading(emily).
met(carl, emily).
met(fred, james).
met(fred, emily).
```

I have been researching so much but I still do not understand what is the problem and how to fix that. It would be great for me to help me.

Comment: You probably mean `compatible(john, X)`? (Capital X)?

Comment: yes, it was wrong typing,sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not surprised you got an infinite loop. `compatible` depends on `friends` while `friends` depends on `compatible`. Are you sure this is what you want?

Please note that if you really wanted your rules to be recursive, you would need a stopping condition. But I don't see why you would need recursion for such a simple problem as affinity matching.

Comment: actually, the recursive relationship was a requirement for one of my exercise, but i just want to understand the problem instead of throwing the question out and let someone did it for me, anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

So what is the problem with your program? Here is a way to localize the problems you have. By inserting goals **`false`** we obtain a [failure slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failure-slice). This is a fragment that shares still a lot of properties with the original program. In particular: if the failure-slice loops, also the original program loops. So the failure-slice shows us a part of the program that *has to* be modified to overcome the original problem. For your query I get the following fragment that still does not terminate:

```
?- compatible(john, X), false.

compatible(X,Y) :- false, reading(X), reading(Y).
compatible(X,Y) :- false, football(X), football(Y).
compatible(X,Y) :- false, friends(X,Y).
compatible(X,Y) :- mutual(X,Y), false.

friends(X,Y) :- havemet(X,Y), compatible(X,Y).
friends(john, carl) :- false.
friends(carl, john).

havemet(X,Y) :- false, met(X,Y).
havemet(X,Y) :- met(Y,X).

mutual(X,Y) :- false, friends(X,Temp), friends(Y,Temp).
mutual(X,Y) :- friends(Temp,X), friends(Y,Temp), false.
mutual(X,Y) :- friends(X,Temp), false, friends(Temp,Y).
mutual(X,Y) :- false, friends(Temp,X), friends(Temp,Y).

met(carl, emily).
met(fred, james) :- false.
met(fred, emily) :- false.
```

But shouldn't just any query for `compatible/2` terminate? For the most general query, the failure slice can be reduced even further:

```
?- compatible(X, Y), false.

compatible(X,Y) :- false, reading(X), reading(Y).
compatible(X,Y) :- false, football(X), football(Y).
compatible(X,Y) :- false, friends(X,Y).
compatible(X,Y) :- mutual(X,Y), false.

friends(X,Y) :- havemet(X,Y), compatible(X,Y).
friends(john, carl) :- false.
friends(carl, john) :- false.

havemet(X,Y) :- false, met(X,Y).
havemet(X,Y) :- met(Y,X).

mutual(X,Y) :- false, friends(X,Temp), friends(Y,Temp).
mutual(X,Y) :- false, friends(Temp,X), friends(Y,Temp).
mutual(X,Y) :- friends(X,Temp), false, friends(Temp,Y).
mutual(X,Y) :- false, friends(Temp,X), friends(Temp,Y).

met(carl, emily).
met(fred, james) :- false.
met(fred, emily) :- false.
```

It is in the remaining part here where you have to fix the problem somehow. There might be further reasons for non-termination. But you **have** to fix this one in any case.

And if this is still not good enough, you might add goals `V = const` into the program. But I think this should suffice...

Answer (score 2):

What Prolog system are you using? Are you required to use a particular system?

Your program as it is will not terminate in a standard Prolog, but will in a Prolog with tabling support, such as XSB-Prolog http://xsb.sourceforge.net/ or B-Prolog http://www.probp.com/ - just add `:- auto_table.` as a first line of your program.

```
| ?- compatible(john, X).
compatible(john, X).
X = john ?;
X = james ?;
X = carl ?;
X = emily ?;
no
```

Comment: For SWI-Prolog add to the beginning of the code:
`:- use_module(library(tabling)).
:- table
friends/2,
compatible/2,
mutual/2,
havemet/2,
met/2,
football/1,
reading/1.`